# Mobile Menu Navigation not linking on blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, blogspot

Please I have a little issue with my mobile navigation linking on www.racityhotel.com. When view website on mobile, the menu navigation doesnt link to their respective pages. I know this forum doesn't threat third part templates purchased but I plead with all humility cos the Nami press support are too slow and havent responded in 4days. My clients are my neck, ready to chop it off. Please kindly highlight what I got wrong and how to. Blow is a copy of the mobile menu navigation codes

```
<select class='selectnav' id='selectnav2'>
            <option value=''>
              - Racity List -
            </option>
            <option selected='' value='#'>
              &#8801; More of Racity
            </option>
            <option value='http://www.racityhotel.com'>
              Home
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/p/about-us.html'>
              About Us
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              Book Now
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              Facilities
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/search/label/Rooms'>
              &#8594; Rooms
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              &#8594; Relaxation Centre
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/2016/04/we-got-best-equipment-for-nice-workout.html'>
              &#8594; Fitness Centre
            </option>

            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/p/events.html'>
              Event
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              Gallery
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              Our Rooms
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/search/label/Business%20Suite'>
              &#8594; Business Suite
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/2017/04/family-suite-single-ngn40000.html'>
              &#8594; Family Suite Single
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/2017/04/family-suite-double-ngn-50000.html'>
              &#8594; Family Suite Double
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/2017/04/standard-double-room-ngn30000.html'>
              &#8594; Standard Double Room
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com.ng/2017/04/classic-room-ngn-25000.html'>
              &#8594; Classic Room
            </option>
                <option value='#'>
              Blog
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com/p/annex.html'>
              Annex
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              Get Discount
            </option>
            <option value='#'>
              Contact Us
            </option>
            <option value='http://racityhotel.blogspot.com/p/contact-us.html'>
              &#8594; Website Contact
            </option>
            <option value='https://www.facebook.com/racityhotel/'>
              &#8594; Facebook
            </option>
            <option value='https://www.twitter.com/racityhotel/'>
              &#8594; Twitter
            </option>
            <option value='https://www.instagram.com/racityhotel/'>
              &#8594; Instagram
            </option>
            <option value='https://tawk.to/404069e8b08ece2896e276ec1ddae3111c9b469f'>
              Live Chat
            </option>
          </select>
```

Comment: You haven't provided a good enough code sample to diagnose the problem, we need more code or a codepen (or something) to show us the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a malfunction in your widget that's causing your options not to create anchor elements on a mobile screen size. Probably a media query went wrong or something of the sort. You can either try to go into the widget code yourself to fix it or write your own media query to give your options an anchor element at a certain screen size.

Honestly, if it was me, I would just scrap the widget and write my own navigation which is much cleaner, but to each their own.